# How can I create two different entry points for devServer and for production in webpack.config file?

Tags: npm, webpack

I have a npm accessible-date-picker package that is a React component. It is setup using webpack. I would like to have two entry points: one for the production environment that builds from the demo folder and one for the production environment. The idea is to make it possible to work with an example code in the Demo folder for improvements and when everything is done, build and publish as a npm package.

I can't seem to get the correct syntax down to make two entry points work. Either I get a production ready version that fails when development is run or I get a production ready version.
Here is the folder structure for the project:

> ```
> |dist
> |demo  
> ||index.tsx
> |src
> | | components
> | | container
> | | | DatePicker.tsx
> ```

Here is webpack.config file that works like a charm for production but can't get development server working. I am not sure how to add a second entry point for the devServer:

```
entry: "./src/container/DatePicker.tsx",
  devtool: "source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    compress: true,
    port: 4000,
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react'),
      'react-dom': path.resolve(__dirname, './node_modules/react-dom'),
    },
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".css", ".scss"],
  },
  externals: {
    react: {
      commonjs: "react",
      commonjs2: "react",
      amd: "React",
      root: "React"
    },
    "react-dom": {
      commonjs: "react-dom",
      commonjs2: "react-dom",
      amd: "ReactDOM",
      root: "ReactDOM"
    }
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'accessible-datepicker.js',
    libraryTarget: 'umd',
    publicPath: '/dist/',
    umdNamedDefine: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              "@babel/preset-react",
              "@babel/preset-typescript",
            ],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          "@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: { modules: true },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
};
```

Last but not least the package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "prepublish": "rm -rf ./dist && npm run build",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "^2.29.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.12.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@teamsupercell/typings-for-css-modules-loader": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^0.4.5",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.41.25",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.8.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.8.1",
    "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.4.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.1",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.6.1",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "^6.0.3",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "node-sass": "^5.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
    "ts-node": "^9.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

If someone could point out how to write a second entry point that would work with a development server would be of great help.

Comment: Do you want to output 2 entry points (1 from `demo/index` + 1 from `src/container/DatePicker`)?

Comment: Sort of. If I am running development server I want it to serve from demo/index but if I run a production mode I want it to run it from DatePicker. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I think it's possible if you can conditionally change your endpoint based on env variable

Comment: Hello @rockon_d. Have you found the answer to your question? If yes, could you please post it as an answer here?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I used 2 different settings that i switched back and forth from.